# Can not get access token in microsoft dynamics in php?

Tags: php, azure, dynamics-crm

We have created application in Azure active directory.Before that, I have experienced by providing same permissions in Azure directory to get access token. But I could not get it by using same application with same permissions now.

[image]
[image]

**My Request is:**

```
  https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?client_id=my_client_id&redirect_uri=https://xxx/msd1/authorize.php&response_type=code
```

**Response**

```
  stdClass Object
  (
[error] => invalid_grant
[error_description] => AADSTS65001: The user or administrator has not consented to use the application with ID 'client_id'. Send an interactive authorization request for this user and resource.
 Trace ID: 6f01144c-4dc0-4911-9923-1cf134d264f0
 Correlation ID: f5765d5f-7109-48a3-89f0-2729c15551c3
 Timestamp: 2016-05-20 06:09:47Z
      [error_codes] => Array
        (
        [0] => 65001
        )

  [timestamp] => 2016-05-20 06:09:47Z
  [trace_id] => 6f01144c-4dc0-4911-9923-1cf134d264f0
  [correlation_id] => f5765d5f-7109-48a3-89f0-2729c15551c3
 )
```

Where i went wrong? Is this permission related problem?

How to get access token for this?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the account you used to register the application is not with the administrator permission or is not in the same Office 365 subscription (tenant).

We can find the requirement:

> Sign in to the Microsoft Azure management portal by using an account with administrator permission. You must use an account in the same Office 365 subscription (tenant) as you intend to register the app with. You can also access the Microsoft Azure portal through the Office 365 admin center by expanding the ADMIN item in the left navigation pane and selecting Azure AD.

Please refer to [App registration for CRM Online](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn531010(v=crm.7).aspx#bkmk_online) for details.

Comment: But, a week before i got the access token,remaining process are went good.I don't know how it changed now

Comment: `You can also access the Microsoft Azure portal through the Office 365 admin center by expanding the ADMIN item in the left navigation pane and selecting Azure AD.` I could not understand.Please explain it.

Comment: how to expand ADMIN item?